# Data.table - left outer join on multiple tables

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose you have data like

```
fruits <- data.table(FruitID=c(1,2,3), Fruit=c("Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry"))
colors <- data.table(ColorID=c(1,2,3,4,5), FruitID=c(1,1,1,2,3), Color=c("Red","Yellow","Green","Yellow","Red"))
tastes <- data.table(TasteID=c(1,2,3), FruitID=c(1,1,3), Taste=c("Sweeet", "Sour", "Sweet"))

setkey(fruits, "FruitID")
setkey(colors, "ColorID")
setkey(tastes, "TasteID")

fruits
   FruitID      Fruit
1:       1      Apple
2:       2     Banana
3:       3 Strawberry

colors
   ColorID FruitID  Color
1:       1       1    Red
2:       2       1 Yellow
3:       3       1  Green
4:       4       2 Yellow
5:       5       3    Red

tastes
   TasteID FruitID  Taste
1:       1       1 Sweeet
2:       2       1   Sour
3:       3       3  Sweet
```

I typically need to perform left-outer joins on data like this. For instance, "give me all fruits and their colors" requires me to write (and maybe there's a better way?)

```
setkey(colors, "FruitID")
result <- colors[fruits, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
setkey(colors, "ColorID")
```

Three lines of code for such a simple and frequent task seemed excessive, so I wrote a method `myLeftJoin`

```
myLeftJoin <- function(tbl1, tbl2){
  # Performs a left join using the key in tbl1 (i.e. keeps all rows from tbl1 and only matching rows from tbl2)

  oldkey <- key(tbl2)
  setkeyv(tbl2, key(tbl1))
  result <- tbl2[tbl1, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
  setkeyv(tbl2, oldkey)
  return(result)
}
```

which I can use like

```
myLeftJoin(fruits, colors)
   ColorID FruitID  Color      Fruit
1:       1       1    Red      Apple
2:       2       1 Yellow      Apple
3:       3       1  Green      Apple
4:       4       2 Yellow     Banana
5:       5       3    Red Strawberry
```

How can I extend this method so that I can pass any number of tables to it and get the chained left outer join of all of them?  Something like `myLeftJoin(tbl1, ...)`

For instance, I'd like the result of `myleftJoin(fruits, colors, tastes)` to be equivalent to

```
setkey(colors, "FruitID")
setkey(tastes, "FruitID")
result <- tastes[colors[fruits, allow.cartesian=TRUE], allow.cartesian=TRUE]
setkey(tastes, "TasteID")
setkey(colors, "ColorID")

result
   TasteID FruitID  Taste ColorID  Color      Fruit
1:       1       1 Sweeet       1    Red      Apple
2:       2       1   Sour       1    Red      Apple
3:       1       1 Sweeet       2 Yellow      Apple
4:       2       1   Sour       2 Yellow      Apple
5:       1       1 Sweeet       3  Green      Apple
6:       2       1   Sour       3  Green      Apple
7:      NA       2     NA       4 Yellow     Banana
8:       3       3  Sweet       5    Red Strawberry
```

Perhaps there's an elegant solution using methods in the data.table package that I missed?  Thanks

(EDIT: Fixed a mistake in my data)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just committed a new feature in [`data.table, v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), with which we can join without setting keys (that is, specify the columns to join by directly, without having to use `setkey()` first):

With that, this is simply:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
fruits[tastes, on="FruitID"][colors, on="FruitID"] # no setkey required
#    FruitID      Fruit TasteID  Taste ColorID  Color
# 1:       1      Apple       1 Sweeet       1    Red
# 2:       1      Apple       2   Sour       1    Red
# 3:       1      Apple       1 Sweeet       2 Yellow
# 4:       1      Apple       2   Sour       2 Yellow
# 5:       1      Apple       1 Sweeet       3  Green
# 6:       1      Apple       2   Sour       3  Green
# 7:       2         NA      NA     NA       4 Yellow
# 8:       3 Strawberry       3  Sweet       5    Red
```

Comment: Hi Arun. In the extended scenario where we have a list of N data.tables (instead of 3 as in this thread) and the same target (join all on a specified variable), is there a more convenient way than linking N expressions?

Comment: @J.G., yes, simply use a for-loop. Assuming 'a', 'b' and 'c' are your tables and joining on col 'x': `ans <- copy(a); for (el in list(b, c)) ans <- ans[el, on="x"]`

Answer (score 7):

You could use base R's `Reduce` to `left_join` *(from `dplyr`)* the list of `data.table` objects at once given that, you are joining the tables with common column names and ***willing to avoid setting `keys` multiple times for `data.table` objects***

```
library(data.table) # <= v1.9.4
library(dplyr) # left_join

Reduce(function(...) left_join(...), list(fruits,colors,tastes))

# Source: local data table [8 x 6]

#  FruitID      Fruit ColorID  Color TasteID  Taste
#1       1      Apple       1    Red       1 Sweeet
#2       1      Apple       1    Red       2   Sour
#3       1      Apple       2 Yellow       1 Sweeet
#4       1      Apple       2 Yellow       2   Sour
#5       1      Apple       3  Green       1 Sweeet
#6       1      Apple       3  Green       2   Sour
#7       2     Banana       4 Yellow      NA     NA
#8       3 Strawberry       5    Red       3  Sweet
```

Another option with pure data.table approach as @Frank mentioned
***(Note, this requires the keys to be set to `fruitID` for all the `data.table` objects)***

```
library(data.table) # <= v1.9.4
Reduce(function(x,y) y[x, allow.cartesian=TRUE], list(fruits,colors,tastes))
```

Comment: np, btw you might be on an older `data.table` version as I don't see the need for `allow.cartesian=TRUE`

Comment: @eddi Yeah, me and the OP both needed `allow.cartesian` (as seen up there)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  When I run `Reduce(function(x,y) y[x, allow.cartesian=TRUE], list(fruits,colors,tastes))` I only get three rows of output.  Should be 8. - oh wait - just read the "provided all keys are set to fruitID" part but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ben then what exactly you are trying to do? if you want to have a control over the columns with which you want to join then you could use `by` inside `left_join` like this `Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., by = "FruitID"), list(fruits,colors,tastes))`. btw, both the solutions results exactly as the desired output you mentioned in the question

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar While Frank's solution works, it requires multiple `setkey` statements in my code every time I want to use it.  I'm looking for a data.table based solution that avoids that problem.  (Imaging all the setkey statements if you had 10 different tables that you wanted to left join in 10 different ways.)

Comment: @Ben the first solution given by me works fine in a single line and is equally efficient as that of pure `data.table` approach. I don't see any reason why not to use it, unless you purely want to stick to `data.table`