# Merging a large number of files from one directory into a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a large number of data files (>1000) in a single directory. I would like to merge them all in a single data frame in R. They all have the same number and types of columns. 
So far what I have is:

```
setwd("directory")
files <- list.files()
for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(files[i], read.csv(files[i]))
```

This creates data frames for each of the 1000+ files. Is there any way to merge them, without having to type out a list of all 1000+ file names?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd like to know who teaches to use `assign` in R to newbies. DO NOT use `assign`. Just try `do.call(rbind,lapply(files,read.csv))`.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480615/data-table-left-outer-join-on-multiple-tables/31481121#31481121) too

Comment: Do you need to 'merge' or are you appending? And if you are merging, what variable are you merging on?

Comment: @nicola why not use `assign` in this case?

Answer (score 12):

The standard way to do this with `data.table` (recommended because of its speed) is:

```
library(data.table)
data <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(), fread))
```

There are also additional functionalities, e.g.

```
rbindlist(lapply(list.files(), fread), fill = TRUE)
```

Will take care of the possibility that some or many of your files have different column names--any non-overlap will be filled with `NA` in those files lacking that column.

---

EDIT: as @nicola mentioned, using `assign` is to be avoided in general unless you really know what you're doing.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-assign-bad) post for further reference to that end.

Comment: That's a great solution. What if I wanted to bind files adding new columns instead of new lines? Is there an equivalent `cbindlist` ?

Comment: @RafaelPereira that's really a different question and i'm sure that it's been asked. in short it won't be as simple as `cbindlist`, but off the top of my head there are two options: 1) use `rbindlist` and then `dcast` the result; 2) use the `on` option and the `:=` operator to sequentially merge the columns. One point to keep in mind is that a merge is essential for adding columns because we should think of the row as a sacrosanct observation--that is, the values associated with each ID are tied specifically to that ID, i.e. order matters, which is a contrast w.r.t. adding rows.

Answer (score 3):

One good way to do that is to utilize `data.table`. This library has two benefits that will work in your case: a) it has a fast way of reading .csv files, and b) a fast way of combining `data.tables` (which are an extension of `data.frame`) into one. So in this spirit, let me propose the following alternative:

```
# if you don't have data.table installed, run install.packages('data.table') first
library(data.table)
files <- list.files('directory', full.names = TRUE)
#create a list to manage the individual files, only used to merge them in the end
FILES_LIST=vector("list",length(files)) 
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    FILES_LIST[[i]]<-fread(files[i]) #this reads your .csv file
}
FILES_LIST = rbindlist(FILES_LIST) #this merges all of your files in a big data.table
```

The variable you are interested in, in the end is `FILES_LIST`.

I hope this helps.